# Bundling pouchDB js library in Aurelia v1 app using requirejs

Tags: npm, aurelia, pouchdb

I'm facing errors while bundling the pouchDB js library in an Aurelia v1 app using the built-in requirejs bundler/module loader.

I isolated the issue in a minimal Aurelia application: these are the steps to reproduce the error:

1. Create a minimal aurelia v1 application using aurelia-cli v2.0.3.

```
npm --version
6.14.15

sudo npm install --global aurelia-cli 

au new
✔ Please name this new project: › test
✔ Would you like to use the default setup or customize your choices? › Custom Project
✔ App or Plugin? › App
✔ Which bundler would you like to use? › CLI's built-in bundler with an AMD module loader
✔ Which AMD module loader would you like to use? › RequireJS
✔ What platform are you targeting? › Web
✔ What transpiler would you like to use? › Babel
✔ How would you like to setup your HTML template? › Minified with htmlmin
✔ What css preprocessor would you like to use? › Sass
✔ Do you want to add PostCSS processing › Yes
✔ Which unit test runner would you like to use? › None
✔ Would you like to configure e2e integration testing? › None
✔ What is your default code editor? › None
✔ Which features do you want to scaffold into your project? › Minimum
✔ Would you like to add a Dockerfile? › No
[makes] Project test has been created.
```

2. Enter the project directory and start the aurelia bundler

```
cd test
au run --env dev --port 9000 --watch
```

The minimal aurelia app successfully shows up at localhost:9000

3. Install the browser-optimized preset of pouchDB

```
npm install pouchdb-browser
```

4. Import and instantiate the PounchDB class in the src/app.js file

```
import PouchDB from "pouchdb-browser";

export class App {

  message = 'Hello World!';

  constructor() {
    this.db = new PouchDB("test");
  }

}
```

As soon as the pouchDB class is imported in the project, the Aurelia bundler kicks-in and re-bundles all the added dependencies without throwing errors

```
au run --env dev --port 9000 --watch
Local aurelia-cli v2.0.3
Starting 'clean'...
Finished 'clean'
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 2.3.3      aurelia-bootstrapper
INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 1.2.1      aurelia-loader-default
INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 1.8.1      aurelia-pal-browser
INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 1.0.0      aurelia-testing
INFO [Bundle] Manually adding package: 2.0.16     text
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processJson'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'copyFiles'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'copyFiles'
Finished 'processJson'
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildJavaScript'...
Finished 'buildJavaScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
INFO [Bundler] Tracing files ...
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.3      aurelia-event-aggregator
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.1      aurelia-framework
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.4.0      aurelia-history-browser
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.2      aurelia-loader
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.1.1      aurelia-logging-console
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.7      aurelia-metadata
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.8.2      aurelia-pal
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.4      aurelia-polyfills
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.5.3      aurelia-templating-binding
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.13.1     aurelia-templating-resources
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.4.0      aurelia-templating-router
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 7.2.2      pouchdb-browser
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 0.0.1      argsarray
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.5.4      aurelia-binding
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.5.2      aurelia-dependency-injection
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.2.1      aurelia-history
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.5.2      aurelia-logging
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.1.7      aurelia-path
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.7.1      aurelia-router
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.3      aurelia-task-queue
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.10.4     aurelia-templating
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.3.0      events
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.3.0      immediate
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.0.4      inherits
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.0.1      spark-md5
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 8.1.0      uuid
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.3      vuvuzela
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.2      aurelia-route-recognizer
INFO [Bundler] Auto stubbing module: crypto
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.1      browserify-cipher
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 4.2.1      browserify-sign
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 4.0.4      create-ecdh
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.2.0      create-hash
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.1.7      create-hmac
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.0.3      diffie-hellman
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.1.2      pbkdf2
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 4.0.3      public-encrypt
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.1.0      randombytes
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.4      randomfill
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.2.0      bn.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.2.0      browserify-aes
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.2      browserify-des
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.4      cipher-base
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 6.5.4      elliptic
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.3      evp_bytestokey
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.5      md5.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.6.0      readable-stream
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.0.2      ripemd160
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.1.2      safe-buffer
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.4.11     sha.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.1.0      brorand
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 4.1.0      browserify-rsa
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.7.1      buffer
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.1      des.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 3.1.0      hash-base
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 4.0.1      miller-rabin
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.1.6      parse-asn1
INFO [Bundler] Auto stubbing module: stream
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.3.0      string_decoder
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.5.1      base64-js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.3      buffer-xor
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.1.7      hash.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.1      hmac-drbg
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.2.1      ieee754
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.1      minimalistic-assert
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.1      minimalistic-crypto-utils
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 1.0.2      util-deprecate
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 5.4.1      asn1.js
INFO [Bundler] Auto tracing package: 2.1.2      safer-buffer
INFO [Bundle] Writing app-bundle.js...
INFO [Bundle] Writing vendor-bundle.js...
Finished 'writeBundles'
```

However, the app now won't load and the following errors appear on the web console

```
...

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    <anonymous> utils.js:3
utils.js:3
XHRGEThttp://localhost:9000/__dev_socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nmn0ZSw&sid=A73E1yB2LRv80nHnAAAA
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1ms]

GEThttp://localhost:9000/favicon.ico
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]

XHRGEThttp://localhost:9000/__dev_socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nmn0ZTn&sid=A73E1yB2LRv80nHnAAAA
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 37ms]

GEThttp://localhost:9000/src/aurelia-bootstrapper.js
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 5ms]

The resource from “http://localhost:9000/src/aurelia-bootstrapper.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff). localhost:9000
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:9000/src/aurelia-bootstrapper.js”. localhost:9000:1:1
Uncaught Error: Script error for "aurelia-bootstrapper"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    makeError require.js:168
    onScriptError require.js:1738
    load require.js:1943
    load require.js:1685
    load require.js:834
    fetch require.js:824
    check require.js:856
    enable require.js:1176
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    init require.js:788
    localRequire require.js:1460
    setTimeout handler*req.nextTick< require.js:1815
    localRequire require.js:1449
    configure require.js:1387
    requirejs require.js:1794
    <anonymous> require.js:2144
    <anonymous> require.js:2145
require.js:168

...
```

I tried to use a couple earlier versions of pouchdb-browser (@7.2.1, @7.1.1) but I get another kind of error on the web console

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined
    <anonymous> index.js:6
    execCb require.js:1696
    check require.js:878
    enable require.js:1176
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    init require.js:788
    localRequire require.js:1460
    setTimeout handler*req.nextTick< require.js:1815
    localRequire require.js:1449
    requirejs require.js:1797
    loadModule aurelia-loader-default.js:165
    loadModule aurelia-loader-default.js:164
    importViewModelResource aurelia-templating.js:3594
    ensureViewModel aurelia-templating.js:4960
    createController aurelia-templating.js:4936
    _createControllerAndSwap aurelia-templating.js:4908
    compose aurelia-templating.js:5010
    compose aurelia-templating.js:5275
    setRoot aurelia-framework.js:215
    configure main.js:14
    promise callback*configure main.js:14
    config aurelia-bootstrapper.js:138
    promise callback*config aurelia-bootstrapper.js:133
    p aurelia-bootstrapper.js:169
    promise callback*bootstrap aurelia-bootstrapper.js:168
    run aurelia-bootstrapper.js:155
    promise callback*run aurelia-bootstrapper.js:150
    <anonymous> aurelia-bootstrapper.js:175
    execCb require.js:1696
    check require.js:883
    enable require.js:1176
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    enable require.js:1557
    enable require.js:1161
    bind require.js:134
    each require.js:59
    enable require.js:1113
    init require.js:788
    localRequire require.js:1460
    setTimeout handler*req.nextTick< require.js:1815
    localRequire require.js:1449
    configure require.js:1387
    requirejs require.js:1794
    <anonymous> require.js:2144
    <anonymous> require.js:2145
```

I tried to use the "alameda" bundler/module loader instead of requirejs, but I still get an error on the web console.
I also tried to install individual pouchDB packages (pouchdb-core, pouchdb-adapter-idb) instead of the preset package (pouchdb-browser) but I'm still getting the same error.

I think this might be one of those corner cases the aurelia built-in bundler is not able to handle automatically and some configuration is needed in the aurelia.json config file.

Did someone manage to bundle the pouchDB library in an Aurelia v1 app?
Can someone please help?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem with aurelia-cli v2.0.3 .  Everything works fine when using webpack.  Is there a specific reason to go with AMD and RequireJS? If I were to encounter this I would just choose webpack and move on, otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RamblinRose. I can confirm that the bundling works fine using webpack. The reason for using requirejs is that I started my project with it and it worked perfectly fine until now.. But it's true that everyone is using webpack and it is a better supported, more feature-rich and future proof solution to adopt going forward. Maybe the time has finally come to make the switch.

Comment: This is an example how tooling gets in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had used pouchdb-browser with Aurelia v1, it had worked previously, although I have not tried it recently. However, I did have to add the following to main.js to get it to work:

```
//to make pouchdb-browser work
import process from 'process';
  window.process = process;
  import {Buffer} from 'buffer';
  window.Buffer = Buffer;
```